# AJAX call inside a loop executed before loop ends

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following problem:

I have a loop:

```
// Code A
. . .
for (var key in dict){
    // Code B
    . . . 
    var list = this.initializeList();
    var selfRef = this;

    jQuery.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',
        url: '/someUrl',
        data: {'sent_data': sendData},
        success: function (recievedData){
            this.function(list);
        }
    });

    // Code C
    . . . 
}
// Code D
. . .
```

Now, the ideal way for this would be if the order of execution of the code is:

1. Code A
2. for loop:

   - Code B
   - AJAX
   - Code C
3. Code D

But, the problem is in step 2 in the loop: first, *Code B* is executed, and next - the AJAX call and then again the AJAX code instead of *Code C*. On the next iteration the AJAX code is executed again instead of *Code B.* It is really important to me the order of execution to be as presented in the list above. As you can see, the variable *list* should be re-initialized for each loop, but instead, we have multiple AJAX call with only the first initialization.

How do I fix this?

Comment: This is bcoz.. Ajax is asynchronous

Comment: re-organize it so that instead of looping and sending 30 ajax requests, you're looping and creating 30 pieces of data and sending 1 ajax request.

Comment: you need to make your ajax request sequential, like send second request only after first one is completed

Comment: @ArunPJohny, how do I do this?

Comment: You can always use jQuerys `$.Deferred`. Deferred objects allow you to control the flow. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Deferred/

Comment: Also, take a look at `$.when` http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/

Comment: Thank you all for the offered help and information, I learned some stuff thanks to you. I solved the problem as @dSquared explained me in his answer. +1 for your help and clarifications!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to make [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) synchronous (instead of the default asynchronous) like so:

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    async: false
});
```

This will cause the execution of the script to wait until $.ajax finishes before it continues executing the rest of the script.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Note however using `async: false` is usually a bad idea, and is a bad idea in this case, even if it does make it work. This will cause the browser to appear to be locked up until the for loop and all ajax requests within it are complete. It may be barely noticeable when testing locally, then much worse when accessed by someone not locally.

Comment: Unless doing any other activity is not necessary while the AJAX finishes its request, you may use this. If the user should be able to perform other actions in the page, this is not the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

AJAX (as it's name states it) is *asynchronous*, which means it is not executed in a specific order. instead, AJAX calls are executed as soon as the server responds to the initial call. What you can do to correct this is add a delay in your function, or add a callback inside the AJAX call so you make sure the code is executed ONLY after the AJAX call has been executed thoroughly

Example of putting Code D in a callback:

```
// Code A  
...

//run Code D if loop exhausted
var dCheckCount = 0;
function dCheck() { // will be called once for each ajax call
  dCheckCount++;
  if (dCheckCount === dict.length) { // # finished ajax calls = loop size
    // Code D
    ...
  }
}  

for (var key in dict) {  
  // Code B
  ...

  jQuery.ajax({
    dataType: 'json',
    url: '/someUrl',
    data: {'sent_data': sendData},
    success: function (recievedData){
        this.function(list);
        // Code C
        ...

        // check if can run Code D
        dCheck();
    }
  });

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. FYI, I solved the problem as @dSquared explained me in his answer. Cheers, +1!